# Overlaying and positioning windows

Tags: qt, qt5

Let's say I have a widget that cannot allow a child widget to be displayed on top of it- yet that's the look I need. I'm assuming the only way to accomplish that look would be to make the child widget into its own window.

How can I make that "child" window always on top of the "parent", and position it to always be at the bottom (with a predefined margin) and centered horizontally?

It should respond to resizing of the parent window as well.

A good example would be like a controlbar for video

(in fact- I would guess that in fullscreen mode VLC is essentially doing something like this... is it?)

EDIT: here is my current widgets layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXSZ2.png

Note that the seekbar is not displaying over the video

Answer (score 1):

The child widget should have `Qt::Tool` window flag, and parent widget should be set as parent widget of the child as usual. This way it will be a top-level widget and will always be on top of the parent.

You should position the child widget manually. For example, you can install an event filter on the parent widget and react on `Move` and `Resize` event types.

Comment: I've updated the question to show current widget layout... calling ui->seek->setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool); does not work (it does compile, just no visual change)

Comment: It should be `child->setWindowFlags(child->windowFlags() | Qt::Tool)` because you don't want to clear all other flags. Also there is no point in putting child widget in the form - just create and set it up manually in constructor. But regardless of all that, it should work, and it works for me on simple widgets. Maybe it's something about VLC widgets or something else in your code.